# Asp.net finding and downloading file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have File Upload form which users use to upload certain files on the server. The files are uploaded in path that look like this.

```
"G:\\VS\\Ticketing System2\\UploadedFiles\\" + ProjectId + "\\" + ticketId + "\\TicketFiles\\";
```

After that I have a repeater which displays some data and have a hyperlink. I want to name the hyperlink`"Download files(" + fileCount + ")"` and onclicked it should display a regular Save As window. Can you give me some code to do that. I've never done something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of files in the directory, you need to use IO.  Then

```
string path = @"G:\\VS\\Ticketing System2\\UploadedFiles\\" + ProjectId + "\\" + ticketId + "\\TicketFiles\\";
int numFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path).Length;
```

Then in your page_load, just change to .Text of the link to include the numFiles variable